# Como verificar se existem números dentro de um input com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Validação de formulário com JavaScript é algo rotineiro no desenvolvimento web, mas sempre causam dor de cabeça! Minha situação é a seguinte: Não posso permitir a entrada de números em um campo do tipo 'nome', mas como posso fazer isso?

Comment: se alguma das respostas respondeu a tua perguntar, marca como resolvida sff

Answer (score 9):

Recomendo o uso da propriedade [Pattern do HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) para o feitio de uma verificação do tipo, pois não é necessário utilizar Javascript.

No caso, seu html seria o seguinte:

```html
<input type=nome pattern="[^0-9]+"/>
```

## Explicação:

`"[^0-9]+"` seria uma [Expressão Regular(RegEx)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) informando que o usuário não pode informar números de 0 à 9(ou seja todos), e o `+` informa que não tem limite de caracteres, você pode colocar um limite substituindo o `+` por `{50}` por exemplo aí teria um limite de 50 caracteres.

## Compatibilidade:

A propriedade pattern está presente em todos os navegadores que suportam HTML5.

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNKj9/)

Comment: +1 por apresentar uma solução mais simples e sem a necessidade de javascript, além de ensinar uma nova funcionalidade que eu não conhecia. :)

Comment: Só um adendo: ele NÃO QUER permitir números em campos de nome, logo, o pattern correto seria `\w+`.

Comment: o `^` nega toda a expressão meu caro, por isso 0-9 está sendo negado, ou seja, vale tudo menos números de 0-9, ou seja NÃO PERMITE números.

Answer (score 7):

O melhor que tens a fazer é arranjar uma expressão regular e ir comparar a input com a expressão.

Expressão regular:

`var verifyInt = /\d+/g;`

E agora pegas na input e usas o `match` para se a input contém os caracteres definidos na `verfyInt` igualando a `null`:

```
if ($("#idInputNome").val().match(verifyInt) != null) {
    alert("A input Nome contém caracteres numéricos!");
}
```

**EDIT**:
**Segue o fiddle**:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/XC4Xj/)

**Fiddle com validação para submeter formulário**:

[Fiddle com submit formulario](http://jsfiddle.net/cesarmiguel/XC4Xj/1/)

Comment: A pergunta do OP é a seguinte `"Como verificar se existem números dentro de um input em Javascript"` até aí sua resposta está certa, porém o OP também diz: `Não posso permitir a entrada de números em um campo do tipo 'nome', mas como posso fazer isso?` aí ele estaria falando da minha resposta.

Comment: Para resolver isso o que fazia era:
- Colocava uma variável global que representava os erros a true;
- Antes de fazer o submit verificava o valor dessa mesma variável, caso fosse `false` fazia submit;

A tua resposta funciona perfeitamente, só tens o problema de haver a existência de utilizadores com o browser desactualizado e não dê suporte a HTML5

Answer (score 1):

Desta maneira aqui já usei e testei e fica legal.

```
$('#id_do_seu_campo_input').bind('keyup', function() { 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); 
});
```

abraço.

Comment: O problema desta solução é que o cursor será levado para a ultima posição quando o valor do campo for alterado com `jQuery.fn.val` para o novo valor.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar desta forma também.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idInputNome").keypress(function (e) {
        var valor = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        return !$.isNumeric(valor) ||
            (e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 9 ||
            e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

2 MODOS.

1º modo
crie através de uma mascara de entrada

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

E depois colocaria apenas para aceitar caracteres ex:

```
jQuery(function($){
 $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[A-Za-z]";
  $("#ID_SeuCampo").mask("#hhhhhh");
});
```

### Creio que irá funciona..

outro método é:

```
function apenas_string(event) {
var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
if (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57 || keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 39) return true;
return false;
}
```

OBS: nos keycode acima são apenas números, precisa descobrir os de letras, porém não sei se funcionária no Firefox...sei que o modo de captar keycode no firefox é diferente..por isso coloquei a var keycode = vários métodos...

```
<input type="text" id="xyz" onKeyPress="return apenas_string(event)" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você cita na pergunta:

- **Não posso permitir a entrada de números**

Está função não permitirá a entrada de caracteres inválidos(numéricos no seu caso), pode ser utilizado juntamente com uma validação final, como demonstrado pelos colegas.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edt_text").keydown(function (e) {        
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((((e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 105)) || !(e.keyCode > 57 && e.keyCode < 96))) {
        if(e.shiftKey) return;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Aqui tem um [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/tr5rx/) de funcionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que a melhor solução seja verificar se a tecla que está sendo pressionada corresponde a um número. Algo assim deve resolver o problema:

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event) {

    if(/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) event.preventDefault();

});
```