# Validar números decimais em Javascript

Tags: javascript, validação

Qual a maneira mais simples e correta de validar um número decimal em Javascript?

Por exemplo, como implementar uma função `IsNumeric` que tenha os seguintes Casos de teste:

```
IsNumeric('-1')     true
IsNumeric('-1.5')   true
IsNumeric('0')      true
IsNumeric('0.42')   true
IsNumeric('.42')    true
IsNumeric('99,999') false
IsNumeric('0x89f')  false
IsNumeric('#abcdef')false
IsNumeric('1.2.3')  false
IsNumeric('')       false
IsNumeric('blah')   false
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada: ["Como verificar se existem números dentro de um input com JavaScript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9121/215) (não considero isso como duplicata, pois se trata simplesmente de evitar dígitos em um campo, mas as respostas contém informações adicionais relevantes)

Comment: Agora que eu vi, o meu caso '99,999' deveria ser `true` considerando que pode ser o número 99999 usando `,` como delimitador de milhar

Comment: É difícil uma expressão que funcione em todos os casos, mas uma maneira de adaptar a expressão pra aceitar milhares separados por vírgula é colocar isso antes do ponto: `(\,\d\d\d)*`. Não é perfeito, pois uma expressão como essa `^-?\d*(\,\d\d\d)*\.?\d+$` aceitaria tanto `,123` quanto `12345,678` e até mesmo `1,2345` (pois o ponto é opcional), ou seja, tem muitos falsos positivos. Resta saber portanto se sua preocupação é maior com falsos positivos ou com falsos negativos, e ajustar a regex de acordo. Ou, é claro, fazer uma função mais complexa e/ou que não se baseie em regex...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creio que seria através do uso de uma expressão regular. Uma expressão que satisfaz todos os seus testes propostos seria:

```
^-?\d*\.?\d+$
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/54N2q/1/). Explicando:

- `^` início da string
- `-?` com ou sem menos na frente
- `\d*` zero ou mais dígitos (para que `.42` valide, é importante aceitar zero dígitos antes do ponto)
- `\.?` com ou sem ponto
- `\d+` um ou mais dígitos
- `$` fim da string

Outras expressões poderiam ser usadas caso de desejasse aceitar uma gama maior de números - como agrupar milhares usando a vírgula (padrão americano), permitir notação científica usando o `e` (comum em linguagens de programação), permitir um `+` na frente além de somente um menos, etc. E um problema "óbvio" com a expressão proposta é que ela não rejeita números com zeros à esquerda.

No fim, é uma questão de identificar com precisão que formato se espera que uma string possa ter para ser considerada "numérica" e ajustar a expressão de acordo. Ela pode se tornar um bocado grande, mas na minha opinião isso ainda é mais simples que tentar um *parse* manual (apenas se aquilo que você considera "número" não se enquadrar em uma [linguagem regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%C3%A1ticas_regulares) é que se torna necessário um método mais sofisticado).

Comment: Nota: poderia-se também usar o `parseFloat` para *tentar* interpretar o número, e verificar se ele não voltou `NaN`, o problema é que se o **prefixo** da string for um número ele interpreta esse prefixo e ignora o resto... De modo que não vejo um meio de se compor uma solução prática usando essa função.

Comment: eu fiz uma alteração no jsFiddle agora ta mostrando o resultado: http://jsfiddle.net/bruxohpotter/54N2q/7/ será que comparando sem o eval seria melhor?

Comment: @HarryPotter O teste com `eval` é só um exemplo, a função `IsNumeric` em si não usa `eval`. Seu fiddle deu errado porque `expressao` é uma string e `esperado` é um boolean, de modo que compará-los sempre retorna `false`.

Comment: @HarryPotter para funcionar o testes, terá que retirar as aspas das chamadas das funções - já que você retirou o eval. Irá funcionar.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Esse problema do `parseFloat` + string prefixada com número pode ser contornado usando-o em conjunto com o `isFinite`, já que ele faz o parse para `Number` e Number desse tipo de string retorna `NaN`

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo realmente faltou retirar as aspas, fiz a alteração: http://jsfiddle.net/bruxohpotter/mVj9K/, vlw